# ^A and ^B separated values

Tags: linux, unix, delimiter, csv

I have a file that has contents that are separated by `^B` and `^A` values. This file has an extension `.tsv` but the values are separated by `^A` and `^B`. I want to add more lines to this file with the same delimited values but I'm not sure what the values of `^A` and `^B` are.

I read around and I think `^A` can also be represented as `\001`

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure how to recreate the balues `^A` and `^B`. I tried entering `contrl + A` and `control + B` but I dont get the same outputs. Also tried \001 but I still cant seem to recreate it.

Comment: if those aren't actual characters (e.g. `^` and `A` that you can cursor past), then they're probably control characters: ctrl-A and ctrl-B./

Comment: If that's Ctrl-A and Ctrl-B then the ASCII values are 1 and 2 respectively. `hexdump` will tell you what's being used.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I tried to c/p the line with `^A` to another file and then `hexdump` the new file. However, I'm not sure if this would work because I think it is copying `^A` as a string. http://dpaste.com/35Z9MH4

Comment: You need to look at the hexdump of the original file. If you've copied it first then the `^A` string may have appeared during the copy.

Answer (score 2):

`^A` and `^B` are [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for the ASCII control characters 1 and 2 respectively.

There is no universal way of typing these. Here are some options:

- Bash:
  `echo $'foo\001bar\002baz' >> file`

  This appends "foo`^A`bar`^B`baz" to the file.
- Vim: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

  In insert mode, this inserts a `^A` (and similarly for B)
- Emacs: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

  This inserts a `^A` (and similarly for B)

You can also simply copy-paste these characters in any graphical editor. However, if you use a terminal based text editor, you have to use the editor's keyboard controls instead of the mouse to copy/paste them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "tr" command to make a temporary file, edit it and then return it to the original. Requires you to have two characters not in the original data (~ and  % in this example).

First translate to get rid of the offending characters:

```
tr "\001\002" "~%" < original-File > temp-file
```

Edit "temp-file" as you need to.

Translate back to the original:

```
tr "~%" "\001\002" < temp-file > modified-file
```

You can check the original and check your work with:

```
hexdump -C file
```